# C# Linq / How to write below code in single query?

Tags: c#, linq, ternary

How can I write below code in a single query?

```
if (flagId>0 && homeOwnerId==0 && COntractorId==0)
{
    var result = _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => x.FlagId == flagId).ToList();
}

if (flagId == 0 && homeOwnerId >0 && COntractorId == 0)
{
  var result = _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => x.HomeOwnerId == homeOwnerId).ToList();
}

if (flagId == 0 && homeOwnerId == 0 && COntractorId >0)
{
    var result = _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => x.ContractorId == COntractorId).ToList();
}

if (flagId > 0 && homeOwnerId > 0 && COntractorId == 0)
{
    var result= _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => x.FlagId == flagId && x.HomeOwnerId==homeOwnerId).ToList();
}

if (flagId > 0 && homeOwnerId == 0 && COntractorId> 0)
{
   var result = _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => x.FlagId == flagId && x.ContractorId==COntractorId).ToList();
}

if (flagId == 0 && homeOwnerId > 0 && COntractorId > 0)
{
    var result = _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => x.HomeOwnerId == homeOwnerId && x.ContractorId ==COntractorId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I would consider applying the [Chain Of Responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) here...

Comment: @phuzi I don't find ilkerkaran's code more difficult to read/understand than OP's, if not easier

Comment: @Rafalon Fair comment - have deleted mine 

Answer (score 4):

COde below should do the same as your example

```
_unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository
  .FindAllAsList(x => (flagId  == 0 || x.FlagId == flagId) 
    && (COntractorId  == 0 || x.ContractorId == COntractorId) 
    && (homeOwnerId  == 0 || x.HomeOwnerId == homeOwnerId)).ToList()
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, I'd consider asking if `.FindAllAsList().ToList()` isn't a bit redundant (or maybe `.FindAllAsList()` is poorly named?)

Answer (score 2):

You might (will) need to catch the edge cases where flagId, homeOwnerId and ContractorId are all = 0 or all > 0 as they are implicitly ignored in your code.

```
if ((flagId == 0) && (homeOwnerId == 0) && (ContractorId == 0))
{
   // handle case
}
else if ((flagId > 0) && (homeOwnerId > 0) && (ContractorId > 0))
{
   // handle case
}
else
{
   var result = _unitOfWork.IToolBeltRepository.FindAllAsList(x => 
      ((flagId == 0) || (x.FlagId == flagId)) &&
      ((homeOwnerId == 0) || (x.HomeOwnerId == homeOwnerId)) &&
      ((COntractorId == 0) || (x.ContractorId==COntractorId))
   ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I assumed those "edge cases" were only missed when writing that wall of `if`s, but nice spot!